# An out-of-grid image next to a div

Tags: html, css, position

I want to stick an image to the left side of the screen and put a div on its right, so both these elements will have the same height and would wrap in case of changing browser's width.

I've tried the following code
HTML:

```html
<!-- some divs berore -->

<div id = "imageSection">

    <div id = "myImageDiv">
        <img id = "myImage" src = "path/to/myImage.png">
    </div>

    <div id = "myText">
        <h3>headline</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum<p>
    </div>

</div>

<!-- some divs further -->
```

CSS:

```css
#imageSection
{
    width: 100%;
}

#myImageDiv
{
    width: 45%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

#myImage
{
    width: 100%;
}

#myText
{
    padding-left: 60%;
}
```

With this solution the image is indeed stuck to the left and has the other div on the right side, but they aren't the same height and won't wrap one under another.

Comment: Have you looked into flex or grid?

Comment: @AHaworth flex actually creates some padding and image isn't situated on the edge of the site. 'bout grid I've found only one article explaining exactly what I want but the given solution looked far from what I expect - the parent div became way higher causing section with text overflow

Comment: What do you want to be the way the height is decided? Is it to fit the image - e.g. so it takes around 50% of width and then, if needed, the text element will be scrollable (if it overflows)

Comment: @AHaworth I want the div to be exactly the height of the image (if it wouldn't be possible I expect the div will wrap under the image) and image to be sticked to the left edge of the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use grid to make sure the height of the text area is the same as the height of the image.

To do this, let the image have the full width of its cell and have the related height (auto). To make sure the grid sets the row height to this rather than take any notie of the text elements, put the contents of that right hand element into another div and make that position absolute. That way the only thing setting the grid row height is the image height.

```html
<!-- some divs berore -->

<div id="imageSection">

  <div id="myImageDiv">
    <img id="myImage" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/200">
  </div>

  <div id="myText">
    <div>
      <h3>headline</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem
        ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
        Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem
        ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
        Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem
        ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
        Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem
        ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
        Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Last phrase</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- some divs further -->
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  #imageSection {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    gap: 10px;
    /* set to what you want */
  }
  
  #myText {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  #myText>div {
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  #myImage {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 500px) {
    #imageSection {
      display: block;
    }
    #myText {
      height: fit-content;
    }
    #myText>div {
      position: relative;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Note: default margins are overriden with the * setting.

For narrower viewports this snippet just sets the image and text as 'normal' so one goes under the other. You could of course limit the size of the text e.g. with a max-height, but the requirement is not detailed in the question.